# For which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, does $ f$ have a minimum in$ (0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ does $f (x,y)=x^2+axy+by^2$ have a minimum in $(0,0)$ ?

What I already have: 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) &= 2x+ay \\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y) &= 2 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) &= 2yb+ax\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) & = 2b\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} &= a
\end{align}
And with that the hessian-matrix $H_f(0,0)$:$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
       2 & a \\
        a & 2b \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Furthermore:

If $f$ has a minimum in $(0,0)$  , all  principal minors of $H_f(0,0)$ need to be $\gt 0$ (sylvester's criterion).
With that I have:

$H_1=2>0$

$H_2= \operatorname{det}(H_f(0,0))=4b-a^2$

However I am kinda struggeling to find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $H_2=\operatorname{det}(H_f(0,0))=4b-a^2 \gt 0$

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: instead of $\frac{df}{dx}$ use partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ for second partials. Also the first partial derivative with regards to $x$ is $2x+ay$

Comment: The answer to the question is "All $(a,b)$ such that $4b - a^2 > 0$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is an alternative approach. Observe that

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) & = x^2 + axy + by^2 = \left(x^2 + axy + \frac{a^{2}y^{2}}{4}\right) + \frac{(4b - a^{2})y^{2}}{4} \\
& = \left(x+\frac{ay}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{(4b - a^{2})y^{2}}{4} \geq \frac{(4b- a^{2})y^{2}}{4}
\end{align*}

The last expression attains a minimum value iff $4b - a^{2} > 0$. Once such minimum value corresponds to $y = 0$, we conclude from $f(x,0) = 0$ that $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write this expression as a quadratic form in the following way:

$$x^2 + axy + by^2 = \left[\begin{matrix}x & y\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}1 & \frac{a}{2} \\ \frac{a}{2} & b\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}x \\ y\end{matrix}\right]$$

It will have a minimum at $(0,0)$ if and only if the determinant of the matrix is positive, i.e., if $b-\frac{a^2}{4}>0$, or $4b-a^2>0$. These points all lie above the parabola $b=\frac14 a^2$ in the $ab$-plane.